# SecurityException: Request for the permission of type AspNetHostingPermission failed

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, code-access-security, securityexception, trust

Setting up a new developing workstation, when I run the ASP.NET (MVC) application from Visual Studio 2008 I get a SecurityException. Any ideas what might be the problem?

I am accessing the data files over SMB (it's a shared mounted as Z:) and I've given full trust to it by running

```
caspol -m -ag 1 -url "\\server\share\" FullTrust -exclusive on
```

The full traceback is:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> **Security Exception**
>
> **Description:** The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by
>   the security policy.  To grant this application the required permission
>   please contact your system administrator or change the
>   application's trust level in the configuration file.
>
> **Exception Details:**
>   System.Security.SecurityException:
>   Request for the permission of type 'System.Web.AspNetHostingPermission,
>   System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.
>
> **Source Error:**
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current
>   web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception
>   can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> **Stack Trace:**
>
> [SecurityException: Request for the permission of type
>   'System.Web.AspNetHostingPermission, System, Version=2.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.]
>   System.Reflection.Assembly._GetType(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean
>   ignoreCase) +0
>   System.Reflection.Assembly.GetType(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean
>   ignoreCase) +42
>   System.Web.UI.Util.GetTypeFromAssemblies(ICollection
>   assemblies, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase) +145
>   System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.GetType(String
>   typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean throwOnError) +73
>   System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ProcessInheritsAttribute(String
>   baseTypeName, String codeFileBaseTypeName, String src,
>   Assembly assembly) +111
>   System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.PostProcessMainDirectiveAttributes(IDictionary
>   parseData) +279
>
> **Version Information:** Microsoft .NET
>   Framework Version:2.0.50727.4927;
>   ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.4927

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a virtual directory that points to a remote share?
http://support.microsoft.com/?id=320268

Also take a look at "Troubleshooting common permissions and security-related issues in ASP.NET"
http://support.microsoft.com/?id=910449

Comment: Yes, I am. Do you know if in that link web server refers to IIS? Because I'm using Casini for development.

Comment: That link refers to IIS, but I think Casini has the same restrictions. Have you tried to grant the FullTrust right to the remote share?

Comment: I don't doubt Casini has the same restrictions, I just haven't been able to figure out how to fix it. How do you grant FullTrust to a remote share?

Comment: I've tried giving full trust with

caspol -m -ag 1 -url “\\server\share\” FullTrust -exclusive on

but it changed nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a command which worked for me:

> C:\Windows\System32>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\caspol.exe -m -ag 1 -url "http://localhost/*" FullTrust

Comment: I get: 
ERRO: Opção inválida: m
ERROR: Invalid option: m

Comment: Okay, I tried a copy-paste from above.  The reason it did not work is because the hyphen before the m is not the real hyphen.